# Which field show the units sold when we request to create amazon advertising report for Sponsor Brand with record type is keyword?

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I request to create Amazon advertising report for Sponsor Brand campaign with record type is keywords. But unfortunately I don't know which field show the units sold by keyword. I tried to use field "unitsSold14d" in postman but it said "Unsupported field for keyword search term report: unitsSold14d". Please help me which field I should use to show units sold because I saw it on keyword report on https://vendorcentral.amazon.com
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

keyword and search term are not the same thing. unitsSold14d is not available for search term reports, but is available for keyword reports.

https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/reference/sponsored-brands/2/reports

Notice it says:

unitsSold14d    Number of attributed units sold occurring within 14 days of click on an ad. Not available for search term report. Vendor only field.

So remove the segment paramter.